# Consolidating offset(1,0), offset(-1,0) and target cell into one code in a loop

Tags: vba, excel

Any idea how I can consolidate the following 3 chunks into 1? I have a lot of worksheet and its getting crazily long... Thanks for the community! :)

```
Dim i As Long 
Dim j As Long

For i = 3 To 73 Step 3
For j = 2 To 33

Set curcell = Worksheets("Earliest Corr").Cells(i, j)

  If curcell.Value < 0.05 Then
    curcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
  ElseIf curcell.Value >= 0.05 And curcell.Value < 0.1 Then
    curcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
  ElseIf curcell.Value >= 0.1 And curcell.Value < 0.2 Then
    curcell.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
End If

  If curcell.Value < 0.05 Then
    curcell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
  ElseIf curcell.Value >= 0.05 And curcell.Value < 0.1 Then
    curcell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
  ElseIf curcell.Value >= 0.1 And curcell.Value < 0.2 Then
    curcell.Offset(1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
End If

  If curcell.Value < 0.05 Then
    curcell.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 45
  ElseIf curcell.Value >= 0.05 And curcell.Value < 0.1 Then
    curcell.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
  ElseIf curcell.Value >= 0.1 And curcell.Value < 0.2 Then
    curcell.Offset(-1, 0).Interior.ColorIndex = 36
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compress those code blocks together by merging the three target cells into one range object. Also in your ElseIf blocks, you don't need your first condition. In order to reach your first ElseIf, we already know that the value of currcell is greater than or equal to 0.5.

```
Dim rng As Range, curcell As Range
Dim i As Long, j As Long

For i = 3 To 73 Step 3
    For j = 2 To 33
        Set curcell = Worksheets("Earliest Corr").Cells(i, j)
        Set rng = Worksheets("Earliest Corr").Range(Cells(i - 1, j), Cells(i + 1, j))
        If curcell.Value < 0.05 Then
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 45
        ElseIf curcell.Value < 0.1 Then
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        ElseIf curcell.Value < 0.2 Then
            rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 36
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Comment: Mark, Thank you for your help but I kept getting error 1004 and when I debug it, the yellow line goes to Set rng=Worksheets("Earliest Corr").Range... for some reason...

Comment: @user3845477 I will take a look at it tomorrow when I'm back at a computer with a Microsoft Office install. If your active sheet is not "Earliest Corr", the problem may be that I didn't explicitly reference the worksheet in front of both the Cells calls in that line. That would be an easy fix.